# MPAndroid Line chart make chart fill from zero line

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am using mp android line chart to draw chart of negative and positives y points with filled enabled.
The problem is it is filling whole wave from bottom of the chart, what i want it like following

[image]

My code :

```
LineDataSet(data, "").apply {
            setDrawIcons(false)
            setDrawCircleHole(false)
            setDrawCircles(false)
            setDrawValues(false)
            setDrawVerticalHighlightIndicator(true)
            setDrawHorizontalHighlightIndicator(false)
            highLightColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
            highlightLineWidth = 1f
            isHighlightEnabled = false
            this.color = Color.parseColor("#F3F6FC")
            lineWidth = 0.2f
            setDrawFilled(true)
            setFillFormatter { _, _ -> chart.axisLeft.axisMinimum }
           
            this.color = color
            fillDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this@VagalToneActivity, res)
            mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
        }
```

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading docs of MPAndroidChart i found this to achieve same graph

```
lineDataSet.setFillFormatter(object : IFillFormatter {
                override fun getFillLinePosition(
                    dataSet: ILineDataSet?,
                    dataProvider: LineDataProvider?
                ): Float {
                    return 0f
                }
            })
```

https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/FillFormatter